# Best way of capturing user email address on website

Tags: php

I currently have a form that on a coming soon page on my web server that I need to capture entered email addresses and send it to my email address e.g. *example@hotmail.com*.

What would be the best way of accomplishing this using PHP?

```
<form method="post">

<input class="emailsubscribe mobile clearfix" type="text" name="mail" 
placeholder="Enter your email" onFocus="if(!this._haschanged)
{this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;"/>

<input class="emailsubscribe desktop clearfix" type="text" name="mail" 
placeholder="Enter your email to stay up to date" onFocus="if(!this._haschanged)
{this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;"/>

<input class="emailsubmit clearfix" type="submit" name="submit"/>

</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are basically asking "how to send email with PHP". Where are you having problems with that, exactly?

Comment: @Juhana I wanted to know about the best method of accomplishing it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I have yet to try anything I was interested in finding out what the general opinion was so I decided to ask a question concerning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**:

```html
<form method="post" action="send.php">
    Enter your e-mail: <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP** (send.php):

```php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']) || !isset($_POST['email'])) die();
$email = $_POST['email'];
mail('youremail@gmail.com', 'Subject', 'Entered e-mail: '.$email);
```

---

You should add some kind of protection like captcha to prevent spamming.

Comment: @methuselah [Creating a CAPTCHA with PHP](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Creating-a-CAPTCHA-with-PHP/) or [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Answer (score 0):

use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) class to send email
or just a [php mail function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. We want to bring great content *to* this site as opposed to sending users elsewhere to get their information :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 inputs having the same name in your form.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email']; // Check first if is a valid email address with either filter_var or a regex. 
    $recipient = "therecipient@email.com"; 
    $mail_body = "Any message you wan to include here"; 
    $subject = "From online Form"; 
    $header = "From: Online Form: <" . $email . ">\r\n"; 

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
}
```